# jquery smooth scroll to an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to scroll down to an anchor link using jQuery?

Like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#gotomyanchor").click(function(){
      $.scrollSmoothTo($("#myanchor"));
  });
});
```

?

Comment: This worked for me: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```
    var hashTagActive = "";
    $(".scroll").on("click touchstart" , function (event) {
        if(hashTagActive != this.hash) { //this will prevent if the user click several times the same link to freeze the scroll.
            event.preventDefault();
            //calculate destination place
            var dest = 0;
            if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            } else {
                dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            }
            //go to destination
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: dest
            }, 2000, 'swing');
            hashTagActive = this.hash;
        }
    });
```

Then you just need to create your anchor like this:

```
<a class="scroll" href="#destination1">Destination 1</a>
```

A demo is also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/YtJcL/

Comment: What's the point of checking to see the lowest point to which you can scroll? Do some browsers mess up if you try to scroll below the last window-height? Chrome doesn't seem to mind; i.e., setting `scrollTop: veryHighNumber` just takes you to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I guess the animation would be cut off pretty hard because jQuery tries to animate the full specified length and the browser just stops scrolling when the window reaches the end.

Comment: How would one go about making the anchor offset (lets say 50px) from the top of the page using this technique.

Comment: @JamieCollingwood dest=$(this.hash).offset().top-50;  I think this would do the trick.

Comment: Nice solution! Just noting for the record that the link needs to target an element with an `id`, not an anchor `name`. I assumed the latter and got really frustrated with this before I looked at your Fiddle more closely. Cheers!

Comment: I might add that adding a `$('html,body').stop()` command right before the animate is extremely helpful for preventing a buildup of animation queues. I used this in smooth scrolling for a table of contents on the page, and clicking several at once very quickly caused the window to then scroll to each destination over a period of several seconds.

Comment: I've tried this on my pc, but it is not working. on jsfiddle it is working. i tried with a lot of JQuery versions, than i copied the code from result in jsfiddle, but it is directly going to the anchor. why?

Comment: is there anyway to add class top active section ?

Comment: be sure to use `.on("click touchstart" , function(){....` instead of `.click(` this is 2014

Answer (score 49):

I would use the simple code snippet from CSS-Tricks.com:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Source**: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: this is probably the better solution if you want all your in-page anchor links to scroll-animate without any frills etc.  Otherwise jQuery.scrollTo has a lot of cool other tricks (check their demo page)

Comment: This is a pretty awesome drop-in solution

Comment: In principle - use **code** not **links** - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Note that the pathname attribute doesn't contain any of the get variables, so if your url only differs by get variables, this code won't work.

Comment: Uhhh, no idea how this snippet could possibly work.  Should be `$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])')`

Answer (score 42):

Best solution I have seen so far:
[jQuery: Smooth Scrolling Internal Anchor Links](http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links)

HTML:

```
<a href="#comments" class="scroll">Scroll to comments</a>
```

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: This really is the simplest solution, plus any future links you want to smooth scroll you just add the class "scroll" to the link.

Comment: This version breaks anchors pointing to other pages.

Answer (score 12):

[jQuery.scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) will do everything you want and more!

You can pass it all kinds of different things:

- A raw number
- A string('44', '100px', '+=30px', etc )
- A DOM element (logically, child of the scrollable element)
- A selector, that will be relative to the scrollable element
- The string 'max' to scroll to the end.
- A string specifying a percentage to scroll to that part of the container (f.e: 50% goes to *  to the middle).
- A hash { top:x, left:y }, x and y can be any kind of number/string like above.

Comment: is this a plugin? because i tried it and nothing happened.. i used this: 
    $.scrollTo("#addNewUA",800, {easing:'elasout'});

Comment: Yes, it's a plugin so you'll need to download it and include it.  It's pretty lightweight though and the functionality is fantastic.  (NB:  I don't have any personal connection beyond using it in a lot of sites)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the code I used to quickly bind jQuery scrollTo to all anchor links:

```
// Smooth scroll
$('a[href*=#]').click(function () {
    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    hash = hash.slice(hash.indexOf('#') + 1);
    $.scrollTo(hash == 'top' ? 0 : 'a[name='+hash+']', 500);
    window.location.hash = '#' + hash;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Looks like you might need the jQuery scrollTo plugin for this code to work?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a version that worked for `<a href="#my-id">` and `<a href="/page#my-id">`

```
<script>        
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this.hash);
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top },'normal', 'swing');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. It is a code from CSS tricks that I modified, it is pretty straight forward and does both horizontal and vertial scrolling. Needs JQuery. Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jdVlxGi16Bq7TToV0oMJ?p=preview)

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top-10, scrollLeft:target.offset().left-10
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [hanoo's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12714767/65387) I created a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.scrollIntoView = function(duration, easing) {
    var dest = 0;
    if (this.offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    } else {
        dest = this.offset().top;
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: dest
    }, duration, easing);
    return this;
};
```

usage:

```
$('#myelement').scrollIntoView();
```

Defaults for duration and easing are 400ms and "swing".

Answer (score 1):

works

```
$('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '#_'));
    $(this).on( "click", function() {

        var hashname = $(this).attr('href').replace('#_', '');

        if($(this).attr('href') == "#_") {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);
        }
        else {
            var target = $('a[name="' + hashname + '"], #' + hashname),
                targetOffset = target.offset().top;
            if(targetOffset >= 1) {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset-60 }, 300);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**I used in my site this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1200, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

});

**You could change the speed of the scrolling changing the "1200" i used by default, it works fairly well on most of the browsers.**

after putting the code between the `<head> </head>` tag of your page, you will need to create the internal link in your `<body>` tag:

```
<a href="#home">Go to Home</a>
```

Hope it helps!

Ps: Dont forget to call:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I used the plugin **Smooth Scroll**, at http://plugins.jquery.com/smooth-scroll/. With this plugin all you need to include is a link to jQuery and to the plugin code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/smoothscroll.js"></script>
```

(the links need to have the class `smoothScroll` to work).

Another feature of **Smooth Scroll** is that the ancor name is not displayed in the URL!

Answer (score 0):

I hate adding function-named classes to my code, so I put this together instead. If I were to stop using smooth scrolling, I'd feel behooved to go through my code, and delete all the class="scroll" stuff. Using this technique, I can comment out 5 lines of JS, and the entire site updates. :)

```
<a href="/about">Smooth</a><!-- will never trigger the function -->
<a href="#contact">Smooth</a><!-- but he will -->
...
...
<div id="contact">...</div>


<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Smooth scrolling to element IDs
    $('a[href^=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function () {
        var element = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: element.offset().top },'normal', 'swing');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

**Requirements**:
1. `<a>` elements must have an href attribute that begin with `#` and be more than just `#`
2. An element on the page with a matching `id` attribute

What it does:
1. The function uses the href value to create the `anchorID` object
      - In the example, it's `$('#contact')`, `/about` starts with `/`
2. `HTML`, and `BODY` are animated to the top offset of `anchorID`
      - speed = 'normal' ('fast','slow', milliseconds, )
      - easing = 'swing' ('linear',etc ... google easing)
3. `return false` -- it prevents the browser from showing the hash in the URL
      - the script works without it, but it's not as "*smooth*".