# smooth scrolling within a div

Tags: javascript, scroll, smooth-scrolling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery smooth scroll to an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198041/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-an-anchor)

I am creating a blog template ([here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30480881/blog_template/index.html)) and would love to allow for smooth scrolling. Links to the various entries are in the sidebar and are simply `<a href="#lorem"><li>Lorem</li></a>` and so on.
Various other questions have been posted here which are similar, but I have tried to incorporate the JavaScript into my website and each time it hasn't worked Common problems are absolutely nothing happening when I click the link, a pause followed by a normal jump to the correct section (with the pause the length that the animation is meant to be) and a completely ordinary jump.

I am new to JS and jQuery, so I would appreciate very literal advice - I am worried that my attempts have so far failed because of one line of code which is taken as given but which I do not know about.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If nothing is happening, it might mean that you are getting JavaScript errors in which case you would need to get a good JS debugging tool to help troubleshoot the problem. Firebug for Firefox works great. Chrome and IE8+ contain a built in JavaScript console. You should familiarize yourself with one of these. These tools will tell you what the JavaScript error was.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this website will help you a bit:

- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

or this tutorial:

- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

Comment: I have previously tried the first link with no success, and I just tried the second (again, no luck). Please could you look at the new source code (at the same address as above) and find what is wrong.

Comment: After several tweaks, it's finally working! I had to change html, body to #content and download another js script which defines jquery stuff, but it's working now.