# Bootstrap jQuery Tooltips and SmoothScroll Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Sup yall,

Thanks to @hanoo 's answer on this question 
[http://StackOverflow.com/questions/4198041/jQuery-Smooth-Scroll-to-an-Anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198041/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-an-anchor)

I've got my Smooth Scrolling working, but my tooltips stopped working. Which made me think, my tooltips also stopped working when I have a modal, mmm...

My jQuery/Javascript is a little dodgy. Also, I'm sure there are prettier ways to code all this (I suppose it'll work then). Any help would be appreciated :)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#NoneSelected").tooltip({
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
        $("#JumpUp").tooltip({
            placement: 'top'
        });
        $("#JumpDown").tooltip({
            placement: 'bottom'
        });
    });

    $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //calculate destination place
        var dest = 0;
        if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
        } else {
            dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        }
        //go to destination
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: dest }, 100, 'swing');
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: Here's the HTML

```
<section id="uptop"></section>

  <div class="jump-downunder">
       <a href="#downunder" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="JumpDown" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="down under">Down</a>
  </div>

<p>body content</p>

  <div class="jump-uptop">
       <a href="#uptop" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="JumpUp" data-placement="top" rel="popover" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="up top">Up</a>
  </div>

<section id="downunder"></section>
```

The DIVs class="jump-uptop" and class="jump-uptop" is purely just for styling.

Comment: May you share some HTML I want to test your script here [at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I also have a problem with smooth scrolling and jquery tooltips. The tooltips seem to handle regular scrolling ok, but when I animate scrollTop the tooltips slide away from their element.