# stop script from scrolling back to top of page onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a simple script that I am using for a tabbed navigation. It just hides and shows a div. However when I change from tab to tab, the screen always pans back up to the top! Anyone know how to get this to stop? My script is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: show your html please

Comment: Try something like this: [Smooth Anchor][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198041/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-an-anchor

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an `preventDefault()` to your click handler.

This will stop the browser from panning to the top.

Like so:

```
//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your click handler to target the `<a/>` tag rather than the `<li/>` tag:

```
//On Click Event
$('ul.tabs li a').click(function() {
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    $('.tab_content').hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();

    return false; // prevent default action of <a/> element
});
```

The reason this is happening is that, even though you are returning false on the click handler for the `<li/>` tag, the `<a/>` tag's click event bubbles up and is triggered at the same time as it is contained within the `<li/>` tag. Since there is no click handler preventing the `</a>` tags' default action, the page jumps to the top – this is assuming the href attributes start with hashes.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Didnt seem to work but I get what your saying, still unable to solve the jump though.

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant HTML markup? Also, creating a JSFiddle that showcases the problem would help us determine a solution.