# Using jquery, How can I scroll to a particular div on a page is centered (vertical and horizontal)?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, scroll

I have a web page that shows a seating chart (where each seat is a div).  In some cases the page is very big so you might have to scroll either right or down to find your seat.

I have a link that includes a the seat name (which is the id of the div of your seat).  I would like have some jquery code that "finds" and "hightlights" your seat when the page loads.

What is the best way, when a page loads, to scroll to have a certain div be at the center of the page.  Once its there I can then do something like highting the div temporarily to make it stand out.

Comment: What have you tried? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579643/simple-jquery-scroll-to-anchor-up-or-down-the-page/8579673#8579673

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
look at [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) and try getting to postion with offset. For highlighting just add a css-class via jQuery

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198041/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-an-anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/wonq8es4/3/

The example above scrolls to a random `div` on the page.

```
// Get a random div or seat
var seat = $('#div' + randInt.toString());
// Slowly scroll to the top of the div element
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: seat.offset().top-20, 
    scrollLeft: seat.offset().left-20
    },'slow');
// When the animation has completed hide, 
// change the background color, and fade in the div
$('html,body').promise().done(function(){
    seat.hide().css('background','yellow').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579673/1085891

Comment: but this only seems to handle the vertical part.  what about the horizontal scroll  . .

Comment: Also, [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/wonq8es4/4/) would ensure the highlighted div is always near the center of the window.