# Does anybody knows which jQuery plugin for smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery, plugins

Hy there 
I'm looking for a way to enable smooth scrolling for a Webbpage as here:
http://unik.weblusive-themes.com/

To be more specific. I'm not looking for a smooth-scroll (click to an anchor-link and slide down to the anchor) but a way to get a smoother feeling when you scroll the page. I guess it's a jQuery Plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: I did. But the thing is "smooth scrolling" is know as the slide-down-to-anchor thing. So there are tons of results for that, but none for ma subject..

Comment: look at [this](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198041/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-an-anchor?

Comment: Pleas read the question: "I'm not looking for a smooth-scroll (click to an anchor-link and slide down to the anchor)"

Answer (score 0):

I use the jQuery plugin Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints) and it's pretty easy to set up and use for vertical and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, but thats not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is use Jquery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/)

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: As I said "I'm not looking for a smooth-scroll (click to an anchor-link and slide down to the anchor)"

Answer (score 0):

I found it: [Smooth Scrolling like Parallax](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Smooth_Scrolling_like_Parallax-Gor)
I think the google keyword I was looking for was "jquery smooth mouse wheel scroll"