# Making tabs scroll smoothly on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have vertical tabs that work well and the content changes when the relevant tab title is clicked. I want the pane of the relevant content to scroll smoothly rather than just appear when the tab title is clicked.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper wpb_tour_tabs_wrapper ui-tabs vc_clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul class="wpb_tabs_nav ui-tabs-nav >
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#tab-e9b37ea4-82c3-7" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Employer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1">
        <a href="#tab-c2c472f3-0bff-0" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Employee</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1">
        <a href="#tab-1438983113882-2-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">You</a>
    </li>
</ul>


<div id="tab-e9b37ea4-82c3-7" class="wpb_tab ui-tabs-panel style="display: block;">
<div class="ww-default wpb_row clearfix vc_row-fluid">
    <div class="no-container">
        <div class="vc_col-sm-8 wpb_column column_container  ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">

                <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <p>Benefits to the Employer: Productivity and Performance</p>

                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab-c2c472f3-0bff-0" class="wpb_tab ui-tabs-panel style="display: none;">Empty tab. Edit page to add content here.</div> 
<div id="tab-1438983113882-2-2" class="wpb_tab ui-tabs-panel style="display: none;">Empty tab. Edit page to add content here.</div>
```

Comment: So what all have you tried in order to accomplish this?  Showing that code will help you get solutions to what is not working correctly.  (Or are you just asking someone to do this for you?)

Comment: When posting a question it is helpful to include what you have previously tried. It helps a lot when trying to find a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery smooth scroll to an anchor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198041/jquery-smooth-scroll-to-an-anchor)